# Add parameter (time) to oembed

Tags: hooks, oembed

I need to add a time parameter to the YouTube oEmbed callback. This time parameter should be set via URL. I found various answers which describe how to hook into the oEmbed callback, but none of them covers the addition of a time parameter.

Comment: Can you give an url example and show us what you tried so far?

Comment: Have you take a look [at the core class filters](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/a1245a4a675ba70d091afac74b2dcc3ce0f5eb91/wp-includes/class-oembed.php#L20) yet? And have you searched the [tag:oembed] [tag archive results](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oembed?sort=votes&pageSize=15)?

Answer (score 2):

No extra code needed.

Simply include the timestamp parameter onto the YouTube link, with the format of hash t equals number m number s.

Or in other words: #t=1m02s

The numbers are minutes and seconds.

Example of a rickroll pre-fast-forwarded to 1 minute in:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ#t=1m0s

YouTube's oEmbed endpoint seems to handle this just fine and returns the code with the proper start parameter added to the video.